# managerAMI not connecting:Connection closed by foregin host

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I am going through the asterisk definite guide and I followed the manager guide
http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html/asterisk-book.html#AMI_id269468

This is my manager.conf file.
I am using Asterisk-1.8

```
    ; Asterisk Call Management support
    ; By default asterisk will listen on localhost only. 

      [general]
      enabled = yes
      webenabled = yes
      port = 5038
      bindaddr = 127.0.0.1


      [hello]
      secret=world

    ; No access is allowed by default.
    ; To set a password, create a file in /etc/asterisk/manager.d
    ; use creative permission games to allow other serivces to create their own files
    #include "manager.d/*.conf"
```

Below is my log file. After using sudo telnet 127.0.0.1 5038 and providing action,username,secret I am getting the following output

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Asterisk Call Manager/1.1
Action:Login
Username:hello
Secret:world
Connection closed by foreign host
```

Below is my log file:

```
[Jun  7 22:55:44] VERBOSE[5328] config.c:   == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/logger.conf': [Jun  7 22:55:44] DEBUG[5328] config.c: Parsing /etc/asterisk/logger.conf

[Jun  7 22:55:44] VERBOSE[5328] config.c:   == Found

[Jun  7 22:55:44] VERBOSE[5328] logger.c:  Asterisk Queue Logger restarted

[Jun  7 22:56:40] VERBOSE[5533] manager.c:   == Client from 127.0.0.1, failed to authenticate in 30 seconds

[Jun  7 22:56:40] VERBOSE[5533] manager.c:   == Connect attempt from '127.0.0.1' unable to authenticate
```

And I am entering the commands(Action,username,Secret) before 30 seconds.I asked in Asterisk  forum and they said to copy paste the Action,Username,Secret.Tried that but still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test configuration is sound. You have to hit enter "twice" after secret or it will timeout waiting for an Enter by itself. Here is a reference link [All command packets are closed with two carriage returns](http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/asterisk-manager-api.html). This article is for Asterisk 1.6 but the same still applies for later versions.